# How to assign arrow keys ti image to move around user

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I was wondering if there is a way to move an image around a userform by assigning the arrow keys left,right,up and down.

I have also seen a lot of threads mentioning setting the keypreview to true. Is this just a matter of UserForm1.keypreview = true and where should this line of code sit.

The code I have so far is below. Any advice would be appreciated.

```
Private Sub Image1_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)

UserForm1.keypreview = True

Const NUDGE = 100

Select Case KeyCode
    Case vbKeyRight
        If Image1.Left + Image.Width + NUDGE >= UserForm1.ScaleWidth Then
            Image.Left = UserForm1.ScaleWidth - Image1.Width
            Beep
        Else
            Image1.Left = Image1.Left + NUDGE
        End If
    Case vbKeyLeft
        If Image1.Left - NUDGE <= o Then
            Image1.Left = 0
            Beep
        Else
            Image1.Left = Image1.Left - NUDGE
        End If
    Case vbKeyUp
        If Image1.Top - NUDGE <= 0 Then
            Beep
            Image1.Top = 0
        Else
            Image1.Top = Image1.Top - NUDGE
        End If
    Case vbKeyDown
        If Image1.Top + Image1.Height + NUDGE >= UserForm1.ScaleHeight Then
            Beep
            Image1.Top = UserForm1.ScaleHeight - Image1.Height
        Else
            Image1.Top = Image1.Top + NUDGE
        End If
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: What's the problem with your code? (besides `If Image1.Left - NUDGE <= o Then`)

Comment: Use `Application.OnKey` to assign macros to the arrow keys.

Comment: @Tim Williams That was my error. So I run the code and when using the arrow keys the square stats static. I use Application.OnKey but I get the error "Argument not optional". I have placed this in a module when trying to run the UserForm. Is that the correct place for the line? When placed in the UserForm code it asks for :=. Is there something I'm missing? Thanks

Comment: That code needs to be in the userform module

Comment: Thanks @TimWilliams I found a workaround in the end. The pic doesn’t have a onkey or keypress event handler